# Proof that the interior of any union of closed sets with empty interior in a compact Hausdorff space is empty

Tags: general-topology, compactness

The question is pretty much in the title, I need to show that given $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space and $\left\{ A_n\right\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a collection of closed subsets of $X$ each with empty interior, then $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n$ has empty interior as well.

Out of curiosity only I was wondering whether the fact the collection is countable is necessary for the claim or if it's true for any such collection of subsets.

Help would be appreciated :)

Comment: The countability condition is indeed necessary. Consider $[0,1]$, a compact hausdorff space, which is an uncountable union of points. Points have empty interior, while $[0,1]$ hasn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A space with the property that the union of countably many nowhere dense closed sets has empty interior is called a *Baire space*.

It's easier if you dualize and show that the intersection of countably many open dense sets $D_n$ is dense. For if $A$ is closed and has empty interior, its complement $D$ is open and dense. Start with an open set $U$ and intersect it with $D_1$. Take a point $x_1$ in the intersection. There is an open neighborhood $U_1$ with compact closure $C_1\subset U\cap D_1$. Then intersect $U_1$ with $D_2$ and repeat this process for a point $x_2$ in $U_1\cap D_2$.

Comment: I got two questions regarding your hint.
1. Why is the closure of the neighborhood contained in the intersection? I assume this is where one uses the fact $X$ is Hausdorff.
2. I assume eventually we look at the collection $\left\{ C_{n}\right\} _{n=1}^{\infty}$ and use the finite intersection property but I'm not sure why every finite intersection from that collection is non-empty.

Comment: @Serpahimz: (1) A compact Hausdorff space is regular. (2) The family is nested. At the second stage you choose $x_2\in U_1\cap D_2$ and use regularity to find an open nbhd $U_2$ of $x_2$ with compact closure $C_2\subseteq U_1\cap D_2\subseteq $U\cap D_1\cap D_2$.

Comment: @Serpahimz: As Brian said, a compact Hausdorff space and more generally a Hausdorff space where each point has a compact neighborhood is regular. I think regularity is the major ingredient here, and Hausdorffness isn't even necessary. (2) A finite intersection is non-empty because it is just the smallest (non-empty) set since the family is nested.

Comment: @Serpahimz And [here](http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Compact_Hausdorff_implies_normal) is a proof of compact Hausdorff spaces being regular. A space $X$ where one-point sets are closed is said to be _regular_ if for each pair consisting of a point $x$ and a closed set $B$ disjoint from $x$, there exists disjoint open sets containing $x$ and $B$, respectively.